# How to profile thown exception in Java Mission Control?

Tags: java, exception, profiling, jmc, jfr

I discovered an *unpleasure* behavior with JMC when execute a "Flight Recording" with tracking of all exceptions enabled.

After recording into panels:

- Code -> Exceptions
- Events -> Histogram -> "Event type" as "Java Application/Java Exception" and "Group By" as "Class"

there are listed **not** all thrown exception but all **created** ones (as object).

There are a manner (or a plugin) to produce a list of thrown exception during profiling procedure?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Flight Recorder (JFR) can only record when exceptions are created. Future versions may be able to record when exception are thrown, or filter per class type.

Here is a snippet that show how things work in JDK 11. Oracle JDK 7, 8, 9 and 10, work similarly, but the events have different names.

```
try (Recording r = new Recording()) {
        r.enable("jdk.JavaExceptionThrow");
        r.start();
        new IOException();
        r.stop();
        dumpAndPrint(r, "Events for exception deriving from java.lang.Throwable");
    }

    try (Recording r = new Recording()) {
        r.enable("jdk.JavaErrorThrow");
        r.start();
        new InternalError();
        r.stop();
        dumpAndPrint(r, "Events for exception deriving from java.lang.Error");
    }
}

 void dumpAndPrint(Recording r, String title) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(title);
    Path p = Files.createTempFile("test", ".jfr");
    r.dump(p);
    for (RecordedEvent e : RecordingFile.readAllEvents(p))  {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

There are two event types

1) jdk.JavaErrorThrow which will be emitted for all exceptions **created** that derives from java.lang.Error

2) jdk.JavaExceptionThrow which will be emitted for all exceptions **created** that derives from java.lang.Throwable.

To keep overhead low only Errors event (jdk.JavaErrorThrow) is enabled by default, for instance if you start your application with -XX:StartFlightRecording MyProgram

If you select "All" in JMC, the "jdk.JavaErrorThrow" event is disabled (to avoid double count) and "jdk.JavaExceptionThrow" is enabled.

Comment: but where does one find the recorded created exceptions? I'm attempting to use this in https://github.com/vorburger/JavaMissionControl_JMC-FlightRecorder-reproducers but can't see them...

Comment: The problem actually isn't where to find them in the UI (in newer builds from https://jdk.java.net/jmc/ it's "Event Browser" instead of "Events -> Histogram") but that non-Error Exceptions do not seem to be recorded, despite exception-level changed from "errors" to "all".

Comment: In a "real" app the custom JFC with exception-level changed from "errors" to "all" actually works. There appears to be some .. optimization (?) which make it not work in a trivialized short lived test example like my https://github.com/vorburger/JavaMissionControl_JMC-FlightRecorder-reproducers.

Comment: I added a code snippet that will explain how things work. The IOException event derives from java.lang.Throwable and is not enable by default (to keep overhead low). To make it work, you have to select "All" in JMC. If you only start your application with -XX:StartFligtRecording you will not get the event. You can however, export a template file from JMC with "All" and start you sample program like this: -XX:StartFlightRecording:settings=myconfig.jfc and it should work